# Woried about my app CPU usage - device is getting hot

Tags: android, performance, cpu-usage, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm developing a music player app using Android Studio, the app works fine. But I've noticed that the phone on which I'm testing the app is getting hot (in the baack), not so much but perceptible,  when the app's running.

So I run the monitor there is a load on the CPU graph, even though no song is playing. This seems to happen only when the app is opened, not when songs are played in the background.

And I've noticed RAM allocation also is weird.

Please any advice. Thanks.

EDIT:
I think this may have causing the issue:

```
    private void updatePosition(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        runnable = null;

switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
case R.id.nav_online:
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                Handler handler1 = new Handler();
                handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        InDeveloppement.showDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    }
                }, 300);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_edit_metadata:
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                Handler handler2 = new Handler();
                handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InDeveloppement.showDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    }
                }, 300);
                break;
}
}
```

Is that a bad method of showing dialog this way?

[image]
[image]

Comment: watch out for unnecessary threads and decrease load on a single thread.

Comment: Oh, thanks. If I can remember, this happened when I added a splash screen and a dialog box that pops up when an item is selected from the drawer

Comment: Every time your clicking the menu you are creating a *new Handler* instance, actually you can reuse it.

Comment: How can I improve it?

Comment: have you tried to run the same app on other smartphone?

Comment: Not yet, but it was working fine before I add the dialog

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal, Tried with another device. Same result and even higher

Comment: Can you share some more code because the code you posted I dont find any trouble with that.

Comment: Which part should I post?